# How add sorting by Flag counter in Controller?

Tags: 8, flags

I get node list in my Conroller:

```
$query = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('status', 1)
  ->pager(10)
  ->sort('created' , 'DESC');
$nids = $query->execute();
```

How can add sorting by Flag counter?

Answer (score 1):

The flag count in another table called `flag_counts` so you should do join with `node` table try the following:

```
$database = \Drupal::database();
$query = $database->select('node', 'n');
$query->fields('n', [])
  ->condition('nfd.status', '1', '=');
// Inner join to get the node status.
$query->innerJoin('node_field_data', 'nfd', 'nfd.nid = n.nid');
// This join to get the flag counts by node.
$query->leftJoin('flag_counts', 'fc', 'n.nid = fc.entity_id');
$query->fields('fc', ['entity_id', 'count']);
// Sort by count.
$query->orderBy('fc.count', 'DESC');
$query->range(0, 10);
$result = $query->execute()->fetchAll();
```